# Generate a customized Rmarkdown document

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have a shiny application in which a user can enter information through a form with various inputs like text, date etc. Once entered, this information is stored in a table in the backend. Now on the basis of this, the user wants to generate a document/pdf in a particular format for printing. Here is a demo of what the final filled up form might look like:

[image]

All the fields, for example, the billed to address, payment method, shipped to etc. are entered through the form and are stored in a table. How do I extract this information from a table and show it in this format? I am looking at parameterized Rmarkdown documents, but don't know how to  get the format correct.

Comment: have a look at this https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html

Comment: @PorkChop thanks for this. I am going through it and it makes sense. What I am feeling clueless about is all the formatting. I also have some stuff like company logo etc. to be added to the document at a particular location. Guess would require some custom css? Any handy guide for doing it as my html/css/js knowledge is quite limited.

Comment: You should be looking at the markdown only, and how to general reports with it. then it will all make sense

Comment: Roger that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As for getting parameters into an rmarkdown file, you can use the yaml header. Since your data is most likely coming from a reactive environment, you have to save the object to the global environment using the `<<-` operator or `assign()`. These values can then be accessed from the Rmarkdown file with the yaml header. Say you have created an object called `address`:

```
---
output: pdf_document
address: NA
---
```

As of the formatting the report, you will need to use `latex` code, either inside the Rmarkdown document and/or you specify a `.tex` file in the yaml header:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
address: NA
---
```

Comment: thanks for this. Considering that I also have png files that need to go into the document, will `latex` be able to do thiis?

Comment: Yes, your png files are coming from an external source, so you can load them inside the Rmarkdown file.